# Did the fight between Orochi and Saitama happened in the webcomic like it just happened in the manga?

Tags: one-punch-man

I readed the webcomic a while ago, and I dont remember the battle between Orochi and Saitama. Did it happen? How did things turn out to be in the webcomic in comparison with the manga?

Comment: Orochi doesn't exist in the webcomic iirc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orochi does not exist in the webcomic.  Instead Gyoro-Gyoro is the official leader of the Monster Association, rather than its "Military Advisor" and shadow leader.

[The wiki's trivia section for Orochi](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Orochi#Trivia) indicates he may have originally been intended by ONE (who came up with the character for the manga) to provide a better challenge to Tatsumaki and the combined S-class, perhaps to create an opening for Gyoro-Gyoro to disable Tatsumaki.